# '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int', but cant find the strings in the data

Tags: python, dataframe, error-handling

I got this error `'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` with this code:

```
zi_diff_2017 = data_red_tot.iloc[:,2:6][(data_red_tot["year"] == 2017)].subtract(data_red_tot.iloc[:,2:6][(data_red_tot["year"] == 2016)])
```

I thought that maybe `data_red_tot.iloc[:,2:6][(data_red_tot["year"] == 2017)]` or `data_red_tot.iloc[:,2:6][(data_red_tot["year"] == 2016)`] do contain strings, but what surprised me is that this two operations worked perfectly fine:

```
zi_diff_2018 = data_red_tot.iloc[:,2:6][(data_red_tot["year"] == 2018)].subtract(data_red_tot.iloc[:,2:6][(data_red_tot["year"] == 2017)])

zi_diff_2016 = data_red_tot.iloc[:,2:6][(data_red_tot["year"] == 2016)].subtract(data_red_tot.iloc[:,2:6][(data_red_tot["year"] == 2015)])
```

I then checked the dataframes via .info() and got confirmed that there are only non-null floats

```
data_red_tot.iloc[:,2:6][(data_red_tot["year"] == 2016)].info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 431 entries, 1 to 9866
Data columns (total 4 columns):
b    431 non-null float64
s    431 non-null float64
si    431 non-null float64
i    431 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(4)
memory usage: 16.8+ KB

data_red_tot.iloc[:,2:6][(data_red_tot["year"] == 2017)].info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 431 entries, 1 to 9866
Data columns (total 4 columns):
b    431 non-null float64
s    431 non-null float64
si    431 non-null float64
i     431 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(4)
memory usage: 16.8+ KB
```

Do you have an idea what I should also check to find the problem?

EDIT:
Full Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-219-66f6f768e275>", line 1, in <module>
    zi_diff_2017 = data_red_tot.iloc[:,2:6][(data_red_tot["jahr"] == 2017)].subtract(data_red_tot.iloc[:,2:6][(data_red_tot["jahr"] == 2016)])

  File "C:\Users\BaranCalisci\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 1493, in f
    return self._combine_frame(other, pass_op, fill_value, level)

  File "C:\Users\BaranCalisci\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5359, in _combine_frame
    this, other = self.align(other, join="outer", level=level, copy=False)

  File "C:\Users\BaranCalisci\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3939, in align
    broadcast_axis=broadcast_axis,

  File "C:\Users\BaranCalisci\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 8811, in align
    fill_axis=fill_axis,

  File "C:\Users\BaranCalisci\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 8850, in _align_frame
    other.index, how=join, level=level, return_indexers=True

  File "C:\Users\BaranCalisci\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3572, in join
    other, how=how, return_indexers=return_indexers

  File "C:\Users\BaranCalisci\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3884, in _join_monotonic
    join_index, lidx, ridx = self._outer_indexer(sv, ov)

  File "C:\Users\BaranCalisci\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 247, in _outer_indexer
    return libjoin.outer_join_indexer(left, right)

  File "pandas\_libs\join.pyx", line 563, in pandas._libs.join.outer_join_indexer

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Small data sample

```
 data_red_tot.iloc[:,2:6][(data_red_tot["year"] == 2017)]
Out[222]: 
      b            s           si         i
mnr                                                
1      76.420562   75.925346   80.022474  78.318538
1014   59.594468   72.901359   72.282378  60.533343
1036   61.411302   61.989852   72.520348  65.580230
1040   67.211456   70.899914   79.363689  75.096387
1061   50.524718   49.964110   73.015946  59.057265
         ...         ...         ...        ...
9517   72.322934   68.839042   76.055376  74.890859
9519   58.167611   57.518538   65.719448  65.140976
964    72.290164   73.651271   74.162528  70.824842
968    51.930839   56.682868   63.408826  59.901983
9866   65.514969   59.013144   67.161826  69.747105

[431 rows x 4 columns]

data_red_tot.iloc[:,2:6][(data_red_tot["year"] == 2016)]
Out[223]: 
      b            s           si         i
mnr                                                
1      76.854202   74.451864   79.998974  78.063673
4      58.976897   67.254973   71.951488  71.543260
27     71.128836   64.647496   72.204597  71.105160
28     52.317802   66.144949   64.518158  63.351971
53     65.253281   55.666438   69.048888  68.434020
         ...         ...         ...        ...
9517   53.312900   55.207277   67.526596  62.432935
9519   59.509448   61.668949   77.609081  66.764866
9519   59.509448   61.668949   77.609081  66.764866
9866   65.513959   61.555514   67.611603  71.011886
9866   65.513959   61.555514   67.611603  71.011886

[431 rows x 4 columns]
```

EDIT2:
I found the issue. The index of one of the dataframes werent fully integers. I caught that by the fact that the index "mnr" werent sorted correctly, i.e. it went from 9519 to 964. Converting them to numbers, seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Can you give a small example of your dataframe?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: Sorry for the last answer. I included the full error and a part of the dataframes.